# Create N elements of struct after input N

Tags: c, struct, initialization

How can i create N elements of this struct after the input N?

```
 typedef struct cat{
 int code;
 int age;
 float weight;
 enum {kibbles,canned_food,tuna_fish}food;
} cats;

int n,i;

printf("Insert a number: ");
scanf("%d",&n);


for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    ....
}
```

I want to create N cats (named cat1,cat2 etc..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either do it statically, by creating an array of `cats`:

```
cats myCatsArray[10];
```

or dynamically, using `malloc` or `calloc` (the latter defined as `void *calloc(size_t nitems, size_t size)`):

```
cats *myCatsArray = calloc( 10, sizeof (cats)):
```

Just avoid the static definition as a local variable of a function, in order to avoid to occupy to much memory in the stack. In case of dynamic allocation you have to remember to `free()` the structs as soon as you don't need them anymore.

After allocating all the N cats you need, you are able to populate their fields according to your requirements.

---

In both cases you can access an element (lets say the sixth one) in this way

```
int myCode = myCatsArray[5].code;
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a function to input a single `struct cat`

```
struct cat inputsinglecat(void);
```

After you know how many cats you need, get the amount of memory required

```
struct cat *memcat;
memcat = malloc(n * sizeof *memcat);
if (memcat == NULL) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
```

Then, to enter cats, use a loop and the function defined above

```
for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
    memcat[k] = inputsinglecat();
}
```

Don't forget to release the memory when you don't need it anymore

```
free(memcat);
```